# AngularJS How to send data only one time (quickly press)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

I've the textarea, and if I press "Enter" button, I need to send data to server, but if quickly press "Enter" several times, "addNewCommentFactory.addComment" send data several times. How can I send only one request (if was quickly button pressing several times). Maybe, I should use delay, before second sending. For example, if time between button press less than 1 second, and next comment == previous comment - do something. Help please.

```js
$scope.sendComment = function(event, press){

  if(event.keyCode === 13 || press){
    
    if ($scope.new_comment && $scope.new_comment.length > 0) {

addNewCommentFactory.addComment($scope.large, $scope.new_comment).then(function(obj){ 
          $scope.new_comment = null;

              $timeout(function () { event.target.blur() }, 10, false);

        });
     
    }
  }
}
```

```html
  <textarea  placeholder="Type a message here" ng-model="new_comment" ng-keydown="sendComment($event)"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable the button when you're processing addComment.

```
$scope.buttonDisabled = false;
$scope.sendComment = function(event, press){

  if(event.keyCode === 13 || press){

    if ($scope.new_comment && $scope.new_comment.length > 0) {

$scope.buttonDisabled = true;
addNewCommentFactory.addComment($scope.large, $scope.new_comment).then(function(obj){ 
          $scope.new_comment = null;
          $scope.buttonDisabled = false;
              $timeout(function () { event.target.blur() }, 10, false);

        }, function(){ $scope.buttonDisabled=false; });
    }
  }
}
```

And in view,

```
<button ng-disabled="buttonDisabled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also prevent duplicate requests globally by creating service for http request with checking duplicates or decorate current $http service.

Check this: http://blog.codebrag.com/post/57412530001/preventing-duplicated-requests-in-angularjs